# How to match the reponse having empty fields(' ') which are not passing NULL in an JSON ARRAY

Tags: karate

How to match the reponse having empty fields(' ') which are not passing NULL, If I try #notnull in match each response, the script is getting pass. but I see few empty fields in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is returning blank spaces but you want to validate them as null, either you or the server is wrong.

That said, you can easily validate *anything* you want using Karate:

```
* def isBlank = function(s){ return s ? ('' + s).trim() === '' : true }
* def foo = { bar: ' ' }
* match foo == { bar: '#? isBlank(_)' }
```

Or you could even use a RegEx:

```
* match foo == { bar: '#regex [ ]*' }
```

Please refer to the docs.